# I have downloaded BIRT reporting tool plug-ins. But it is not showing in eclipse tool.

Tags: birt

I am trying to learn BIRT tool. I have downloaded BIRT tool plug-ins in eclipse. But downloaded plug ins not available in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

As my understand is better to download directly from the official page, this is the link:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-4.6.0-201606072112/birt-report-designer-all-in-one-4.6.0-20160607-win32.win32.x86_64.zip

To start using it you need to create a new project:

[file]->[New]->[Other]->[Business Intelligence and Reporting Tools]->[Report Project]

Then In the [Window]->[Open Perspective]->[Other...]->[Report Design]

On the Show View [Navigator] you will right click and [New]->[Report].

Hope it can helps.